# Dynamic property accessor

Tags: javascript, object, accessor

Given a property accessor in dot notation eg. `google.maps.places`, I need to evaluate the statement to get the property value.

```
var str = 'google.maps.places';
var statement = 'window["' + str.split('.').join('"]["') + '"]';
eval(statement);
```

Ofcourse, it works but I've never used `eval` in production and would never want to, so just wondering if there's a better way? Also because this is a quick example but the function could accept accessors of any levels, just `google` or `google.maps` or even `google.maps.places.autocomplete`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split()` and `reduce()`

```js
let obj = {
  google:{
    maps:{
      places:["Place 1","place 2"]
    }
  }
}
function findItem(obj,path){
      path = path.split('.');
      return path.reduce((ac,a) => (ac.hasOwnProperty(a) ? ac[a] : {}),obj);
}

console.log(findItem(obj,'google.maps.places'))
```

Comment: I think you forgot `return` statement at the end

Comment: @Shilly No @Andrey meant if not returning from function he is not taking about callback of `reduce`